# Prevent State Overwrite React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a case like this
I have a current product

```
0: {id: "abc", name: "bigu", qty: 1, remarks: "nice"},
1: {id: "def", name: "moo", qty: 1, remarks: "handsome"}
```

When I add a new product

```
0: {id: "abc", name: "bigu", qty: 1, remarks: ""},
1: {id: "def", name: "moo", qty: 1, remarks: ""},
2: {id: "ghi", name: "ucing", qty: 1, remarks: ""},
3: {id: "jkl", name: "kepi", qty: 1, remarks: ""}
```

this is my first state and useEffect that change product list everytime I called addReq.product

```
const [productsLists, setProductsLists] = useState<Product[]>(addReq.product)

useEffect(() => {
    setProductsLists(addReq.product)
  }, [addReq.product])
```

I want the setProductsLists is not overwrite the current product that I already have and just adding a new product to the current array. The addReq is from my redux.

I already tried this methods but it causing infinite loops.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setProductsLists(prevProducts => {
    // Create a new array with the existing products and new products
    const updatedProducts = [...prevProducts, ...addReq.product];

    // Update the remarks of only the new products to an empty string
    const updatedProductsLists = updatedProducts.map((product, index) => {
      if (index >= prevProducts.length) {
        return { ...product, remarks: "" };
      }
      return product;
    });

    return updatedProductsLists;
  });
}, [addReq.product]);
```

Comment: Why do you use a `useEffect` instead of the setter function directly? I'm pretty sure [you should not use](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#) a `useEffect` like this.

Comment: Because I want to update the productsLists everytime there is a new product added and I don't know how to use setter function directly.

Comment: You said the request is from redux, why don't you store the products in Redux?

Comment: What exactly does "new product" mean in this scenario? Is a "new product" one that isn't already in the `productsLists` array? In other words, is your code generating duplicates and you need to only append not-already included elements from the `addReq.product` array? *Why* are you duplicating the `addReq` state from redux into local component state? It's rather unclear what you are trying to accomplish or what the issue really is here. Can you [edit] to clarify and provide better data examples that fit a set of reproduction steps?

Answer (score 1):

> do not modified products properties **remarks** at the end it will modified all avaliable products in the array with remarks properties

> do one thing update the require object first and then add it to array

```js
useEffect(() => {
let updateProdect = {...addReq.product,remarks: "" }
  setProductsLists(prevProducts => {
    // Create a new array with the existing products and new products
    const updatedProducts = [...prevProducts, ...updateProdect];

    // Update the remarks of only the new products to an empty string
    const updatedProductsLists = updatedProducts.map((product, index) => {
      if (index >= prevProducts.length) {
        return { ...product};
      }
      return product;
    });

    return updatedProductsLists;
  });
}, [addReq.product]);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use UseRef:

```
const productsList = useRef<Product[]>();
useEffect(() => {
    productsList.ref = { ...productsList, addReq.product };
}, [addReq.product]);
```

But, you should understand that changing productsList.ref does not re-render the component: no further changes occur(you cannot render newly modified "productsList").

you'd better consider using useSelector and useDispatch(with reducers).

```
const products = useSelector(state => state.products);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const setProducts = (newProducts: Product[]) => {
    dispatch(setProducts([...products, ...newProducts]));
}
```

calling setProducts will lead to a "modified" productList